# How to get drive label in Linux using C from userspace

Tags: c, linux, label, drives

I need to get a label for specific device using c/c++ (and no d-bus) in linux. The problem is that i can't just open device and read it's information (for extN it is very easy to get label from device) because reading from /dev/xxx requires root privileges.

Comment: A program running with root privileges is still "user space" (not "kernel space").

Answer (score 1):

I think in most distributions now you have

```
/dev/disk/by-label/
```

which is filled with symlinks that point to the real device.

Comment: Well, it is not the best way i think... As i know, these folders requires udev in system. Maybe it's better to use libudev? However i didn't find proper functions in it's documentation.

Comment: If your code is not needed early in the boot process, I think this usually works. I have no experience with libudev, but I guess if you want to have access to the raw device, you'd have to have root access, no? The advantage of this directory here is that you see exactly what the system wants to export to user space.