# Getting disk label in Linux in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get drive label in Linux using C from userspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112964/how-to-get-drive-label-in-linux-using-c-from-userspace)

How can I obtain label of a disk by its file name (/dev/sda1, e.g.) in a program written in C/C++?

Comment: Look into the source code of utilities giving that label.

Comment: @PlasmaHH the accepted answer 404's

Comment: @Joe: googling for the name of the link in the answer leads to the new uri (kernel.org has been extensively restructured). shouldnt be too hard to do that. also you could be so nice as to edit the answer to point to the new url. or leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can code the C or C++ equivalent of this command:

```
find -L /dev/disk/by-label -inum $(stat -c %i /dev/sda1) -print
```

That is, `stat()` the device file you care about and remember its inode number. Iterate over all of the files in /dev/disk/by-label, and `stat()` each of them. When the inode number matches, then the name of the matched file is the label of that disk.

If it were me, I'd code the above algorithm in C++, using [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm).

Comment: Thanks. I knew about this way - using /dev/disk/by-label. But idea of applying inodes is interesting. The only note: lstat() provides information about the link itself, not about the file it points to. So one must use just stat() for the both cases.

Comment: re: lstat. You are right, of course. I fixed my answer.

Comment: The beginning of the command should read  find -L /dev/disk/by-path.

Comment: No, I really meant `/dev/disk/by-label`. Searching `/dev/disk/by-path` won't give me what the OP asked for -- the label.